# passing callback parameters ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, callback

I need some help with ajax callbacks. I'm trying to pass certain parameters after ajax is being called

```
        var dataString = 'string=' + string;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "file.php",
            data: dataString,
            success: function(data){

                $(".selector").html(data)

        }
        });
```

Okay so if my file.php has some mysql queries and I'm trying to echo out values

```
echo $picture;
echo $title;
echo $additional_values;
```

How do I echo out certain values and pass it through ajax

So if I echo those out in my php file, and output it through my ajax function(data), it will output everything into `$(".selector").html(data)` (`<div class="selector"></div>`), however, I'm trying to output one thing at a time

```
success: function(data){
  $(".picture").html(data); // echo's out picture in my picture div class
  $(".title").html(data); // echo's out title in my title div class
  $(".additional_values").html(data); // echo's out to the div class...
}
```

If someone can shine some light towards me, that'll be great!

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP

```
$data = array('picture'=>$picture,
              'title'=>$title,
              'values'=>$additional_values,
             );

print json_encode($data);
```

JavaScript

```
    var dataString = 'string=' + string;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "file.php",
        data: dataString,
        datatype: 'json',
        success: function(data){
            $(".picture").html(data.picture);
            $(".title").html(data.title);
            $(".additional_values").html(data.values);

        }
    });
```

Comment: You probably also need to change the $.ajax datatype to json

Comment: @Downvoter: can you please tell what is wrong with my answer? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use JSON. JSON is a serialization format that allows you to "convert" an object to string an convert a string back to object. PHP has a built-in function to encode to JSON string, called `json_encode`:

PHP code

```
file.php
<?php
//... Your logic here
header("Content-type: application/json"); //'Tell' the browser that it's a JSON response
$returnData = array('picture'=>$picture, 'title'=>$title, 'values'=>$additional_values);
echo json_encode($returnData); //Encode $returnData to JSON string
?>
```

Now, jQuery can receive this string and convert it to a javascript object automatically. We have an object in the `data` parameter

JavaScript

```
var dataString = 'string=' + string;
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "file.php",
    data: dataString,
    success: function(data){
       //At this point, data is just as php's $returnData, so it has 3 properties
       //picture, title and values.
       $(".picture").html(data.picture);
       $(".title").html(data.title);
       $(".additional_values").html(data.values);
    }
});
```

JSON is available in many languages, and is the defacto interchange format in AJAX. More information on http://json.org.

Hope this helps. Cheers